# count using a case statement to find range

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am trying to count the number of times number a list of numbers fall into a certain range.

Data:

```
advance:
--------
5000
5000
10125
5000
0
15000
[NULL]
7000
8000
[NULL]
7000
2275
6000
2000
4000
7000
4000
8000
```

Using a case statement and count in one query.
Case Statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN
        advance > 10000
    THEN
        /* Display as 'High'*/
    WHEN
        advance >= 5000 and advance <= 10000
    THEN
        /*Display as 'Moderate'*/
    WHEN
        advance < 5000
    THEN
        /*Display as 'Low'*/
    ELSE
       /*Display as 'N/A'*/ 
END
```

But the twist with this is that the data has to be formatted in a single cell.
What I have so far:

```
"i.  Category       " + "Number" + char(13)+char(10) +
"ii.  -----------------------------------" + char(13)+char(10) +
"iii. High:            " + /*Display High*/ + char(13)+char(10) +
"iv. Low:            " + /*Display Low*/ + char(13)+char(10) +
"v.  Moderate:    " + /*Display Moderate*/ + char(13)+char(10) +
"vi. N/A              " + /*Display N/A */ +
```

So the end results should look like this:

```
i.   Category     Number
ii.  --------------------
iii. High         5
iv.  Low     
v.   Moderate     
vi.  N/A
```

I am using Sybase to write this query and normally I don't ask for help. I am just stuck and having trouble wrapping my brain around this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it works but I hope my idea helps you

```
select "i.  Category       " + "Number" + char(13)+char(10) +
"ii.  -----------------------------------" + char(13)+char(10) +
"iii. High:            " + cast((select count(1)
                                 from tabData
                                 where  advance > 10000) as varchar) + char(13)+char(10) +
"iv. Low:            " + cast((select count(1)
                               from tabData
                               where  advance >= 5000  
                               and advance <= 10000) as varchar) + char(13)+char(10) +
"v.  Moderate:    " + cast((select count(1)
                            from tabData
                            where advance < 5000) as varchar) + char(13)+char(10) +
"vi. N/A              " + cast((select count(1)
                                from tabData
                                where  advance is null) as varchar)
```

Comment: Me too! I cannot believe the answer was so incredibily simple and I feel like I was overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT Category, Count(Category)
FROM (SELECT CASE
              WHEN advance > 10000
                 THEN 'High' as Category
              WHEN advance >= 5000 and advance <= 10000
                 THEN 'Moderate' as Category
              WHEN advance < 5000
                 THEN 'Low' as Category
              ELSE
                 'N/A' as Category
             END
        FROM your_table_name) as CategoriesResult
GROUP BY Category
```

If you would like to generate a single text value you can wrap it into an extra query for that and append each record of the final result set to the resultant text value:

```
DECLARE @result AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @result = "i.  Category       Number" + char(13) + char(10) +
              "ii.  -----------------------------------" + char(13) + char(10)

SELECT @result = @result + CONVERT(varchar(8), Category) 
                         + " "
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CategoryCount) + char(13) + char(10)
 FROM
   (SELECT Category, Count(Category) as CategoryCount
       FROM (SELECT CASE
                     WHEN advance > 10000
                        THEN 'High' as Category
                     WHEN advance >= 5000 and advance <= 10000
                        THEN 'Moderate' as Category
                     WHEN advance < 5000
                        THEN 'Low' as Category
                     ELSE
                        'N/A' as Category
                    END
               FROM your_table_name) as CategoriesResult
       GROUP BY Category
   )SourceTable
```

Comment: What I was trying to say, but too lazy/slow to explain +1

Comment: +1 but the OP wants the results in a single field, can this SQL be wrapped somehow to achieve this?

Comment: @philreed - goot point.. I didn't realize that initially; I've updated the post

Comment: Strange it looks like it would work but I keep getting a syntax error near the keyword "AS" and a must declare variable "@result"

Comment: did you just copy paste the answer? It looks like I had a typo at "DECLARE @result AS"; it was "DELCARE"